# InlineAssignHelper does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, captcha

I am trying to use an API from a website, here is the example page: `http://www.captchatronix.com/api.php` **not affiliated or anything with the website**

Their C# code contains a function that is not declared `InlineAssignHelper` which can be found in this part of the code (**line 38 on their website)**:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((InlineAssignHelper(bytesRead, fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))) != 0) {
memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
fileStream.Close();
```

What does it really do ?

I am trying to solve this problem for 2 hours now.

Comment: Wow, their sample code is a *mess*.  I imagine you may have to contact the vendor using the form on their website (or any other contact information you may have for them).  Given the state of their code and documentation though, you may also want to entertain the possibility of not using their software.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as

```
while (bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))
```

This happens when you convert code to VB.NET and then back with [DeveloperFusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/).

The function is needed to convert the above line of C# code into VB.NET

```
Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, ByVal value As T) As T
  target = value
  Return value
End Function
```

The C#-equivalent being

```
private static T InlineAssignHelper<T>(ref T target, T value)
{
    target = value;
    return value;
}
```

Notice the ByRef, assigning a target a value, and returning the value.
You couldn't otherwise do it in VB.NET

Obviously, here it uses object instead of the template parameter.

```
private static object InlineAssignHelper(ref object target, object value)
{
    target = value;
    return value;
}
```

Also, if it's a class and not a value type, you can omit the byref, making it just

```
private static object InlineAssignHelper(object target, object value)
{
    target = value;
    return value;
}
```

as classes are passed by reference, which is why it is all the same in this case.